# Qt 4.8 signal namespace issue

Tags: c++, qt

I am having an issue compiling some old code after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015.
The class that contains the signal is defined like this:

```
namespace aaa {
namespace bbb {

class MyCombo : public QComboBox
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

  MyCombo(QWidget* parent=0);

Q_SIGNALS:

  void mySignal(ccc::SomeType::SomeTypeValues);
};

} // bbb
} // aaa
```

SomeType is defined in a different header file like this:

```
namespace aaa {
namespace ccc {

class SomeType
{
public:
  enum SomeTypeValues { SomeValue=0, SomeOtherValue };
};

} // ccc
} // aaa
```

When I compile the code, I get:

```
error C2327: 'QWidget::ccc': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
```

I tried to change the signal signature to:

```
void mySignal(aaa::ccc::SomeType::SomeTypeValues);
```

This compiles, but when the signal is emitted, neither of the slots connected to this signal get triggered.

Comment: google for "register metatype"

Comment: I have added:
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ccc::SomeType);
But it made no difference.

Comment: Literally the first result from googling the exact keywords gives you the exact solution to your problem, which is only 5 lines, yet you won't read the whole thing?

Comment: The first result I get is "Register a Meta Type in Qt" in stackoverflow.
Its not the same problem - he has a qobject class and I dont. He doesn't even get the same error as I do.